# Is it possible to get current background color of UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I know about the currentBackgroundImage property for UIButtons, but is there anyway to get a simple backgroundColor from a UIButton?

Comment: Are you trying to get a color from the button's background color or background image?

Comment: I would suggest you, not to ask the question whose answer can be given in one word (yes or no). You could have asked How to get current background color.... :)

Comment: This question would be easily answered by looking at the [spec](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html).  You just have to understand that UIButton is a subclass of UIView (which you can see in the "Inherits from" portion of the spec), and `backgroundColor` is a property of UIView, not of UIButton directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I get your question right you just want to get the background color of a button and store it?

```
UIColor* buttonColor = button.backgroundColor;
```

`backgroundColor` is a `copy` property with both a setter and a getter. You can use dot notation to simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, the answer should only be in YES or NO.

But I would like to explain, **YES you can retrieve** and set the background color of your UIButton.

```
UIButton *blueButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
//for setting
blueButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f 
                                             green:0.0f
                                              blue:1.0 
                                               pha:1.0]; 
//for getting
UIColor *myBlueButtonColor = blueButton.backgroundColor;
```